# HTTPS Not working on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and Apache 2.4

Tags: 14.04, server, https, apache2.4

Ok, I've been trying to fix this for about a week but can't find anything that's similar enough to my situation to fix. I'm on a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I've set up everything on the server yet for some reason Apache isn't serving HTTPS requests.

More info:
Running `netstat -tulpn | grep apache` shows the following:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN   3680/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN   3680/apache2
```

So it's definitely listening on the correct port. Running `openssl s_client -connect <servername>:443 -showcerts` shows that it's not serving HTTPS requests:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140318680839840:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown     protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Here is my vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin nathan@<servername>.co.uk
    ServerName <servername>.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.<servername>.co.uk

    # FPM config
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/<servername>.co.uk/$1
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    # TLS
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-mail-<servername>.co.uk.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-key-decrypted-mail-<servername>.co.uk.key

    DocumentRoot /var/www/<servername>.co.uk
    <Directory /var/www/<servername>.co.uk>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride ALL
            Options All -Indexes
            Require all granted
            Require ssl

            # Rewrite
            RewriteBase /

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/custom_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is the contents of my error.log, so it says that it's running openssl:

```
[Sat Feb 07 11:08:17.762312 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3680:tid 139763219974016] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 07 11:08:18.843199 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4671:tid 140013857027968] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_gnutls/0.5.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 07 11:08:18.843274 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4671:tid 140013857027968] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And I've definitely got the ssl module enabled: `ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jan 29 09:59 access_compat.load -> ../mods-available/access_compat.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 29 09:59 alias.conf -> ../mods-available/alias.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 29 09:59 alias.load -> ../mods-available/alias.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 09:59 auth_basic.load -> ../mods-available/auth_basic.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 09:59 authn_core.load -> ../mods-available/authn_core.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 09:59 authn_file.load -> ../mods-available/authn_file.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 09:59 authz_core.load -> ../mods-available/authz_core.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 09:59 authz_host.load -> ../mods-available/authz_host.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 09:59 authz_user.load -> ../mods-available/authz_user.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jan 29 09:59 autoindex.conf -> ../mods-available/autoindex.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jan 29 09:59 autoindex.load -> ../mods-available/autoindex.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jan 29 09:59 deflate.conf -> ../mods-available/deflate.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jan 29 09:59 deflate.load -> ../mods-available/deflate.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 29 09:59 dir.conf -> ../mods-available/dir.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 29 09:59 dir.load -> ../mods-available/dir.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 29 09:59 env.load -> ../mods-available/env.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 29 09:59 filter.load -> ../mods-available/filter.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 31 12:19 gnutls.conf -> ../mods-available/gnutls.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 31 12:19 gnutls.load -> ../mods-available/gnutls.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jan 29 09:59 mime.conf -> ../mods-available/mime.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jan 29 09:59 mime.load -> ../mods-available/mime.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jan 29 09:59 mpm_event.conf -> ../mods-available/mpm_event.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jan 29 09:59 mpm_event.load -> ../mods-available/mpm_event.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jan 29 09:59 negotiation.conf -> ../mods-available/negotiation.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jan 29 09:59 negotiation.load -> ../mods-available/negotiation.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 29 10:28 proxy.conf -> ../mods-available/proxy.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 29 10:28 proxy_fcgi.load -> ../mods-available/proxy_fcgi.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 29 10:28 proxy.load -> ../mods-available/proxy.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jan 29 10:21 rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jan 29 09:59 setenvif.conf -> ../mods-available/setenvif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jan 29 09:59 setenvif.load -> ../mods-available/setenvif.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jan 30 16:48 socache_shmcb.load -> ../mods-available/socache_shmcb.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 30 16:48 ssl.conf -> ../mods-available/ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 30 16:48 ssl.load -> ../mods-available/ssl.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 29 09:59 status.conf -> ../mods-available/status.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 29 09:59 status.load -> ../mods-available/status.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb  7 10:41 vhost_alias.load -> ../mods-available/vhost_alias.load
```

Now browsing to `https://<servername>.co.uk` fails with `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` in Firefox, but going to `http://<servername>.co.uk:443` works (yet obviously not with TLS). There are no errors in any of the log files, the vhost is definitely getting loaded, but for some reason Apache is just refusing to serve HTTPS to clients. Am I missing a module, or something in my configuration?

Apologies for the massive data dump but I just wanted to provide as much helpful info as possible!

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm running on the Rackspace Cloud, so the way I eventually fixed it was by using a load balancer. That handled the HTTPS part and just forwarded HTTP traffic to my server. Not ideal, but did work.

Comment: Try increase [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) (for whole Apache or only for SSL module), and check error.log again for more verbose errors.

Comment: Did you make sure that the SSL functionality is enabled with `a2enmod ssl`?